# Laravel : How can i insert data on multiple tables

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.5

Do not know which way is better to perform this operations.Having a two tables `inquiry_master` and `inquiry_plan`.Already define a relationship.

Migration files:

```
>> INQUIRY_MASTER

public function up()
{
   Schema::create('inquiry_master', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->dateTime('created_date_time')->nullable();
        $table->unsignedInteger('user_id')->nullable();
        $table->string('stitch_video_path')->nullable();
        $table->enum('completion_status',['Complete','Pending']);
        $table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users');
    });
}

>> INQUIRY_PLAN

public function up()
{
   Schema::create('inquiry_plan', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->unsignedInteger('inquiry_id');
        $table->string('title_vacation');
        $table->string('email');
        $table->string('phone_no', 20)->nullable();
        $table->dateTime('start_date')->nullable();
        $table->dateTime('end_date')->nullable();
        $table->foreign('inquiry_id')->references('id')->on('inquiry_master');
    });
}
```

Currently define a function to insert data only on `inquiry_plan`table.
function which define on my controller.

Controller Code :

```
public function addactivity(Request $request) {

        $validator = Validator::make($request->all(), Inquiryplan::planRules(), Inquiryplan::PlanMessages());
        if ($validator->fails()) {
            return back()->with('error', "Unable to send contact request.!!")->withInput()->withErrors($validator);
        }
        $plandetails = Inquiryplan::SaveOrUpdate($request);
        if($plandetails !== false) {
            return redirect()->route('plan')->with('success', trans('Plan details added successfully.!!'));
        } else {
            return back()->with('error', "Unable to save plan details.!!")->withInput();
        }
}
```

And finally save function on my model `inquiryplan` model.

Model code :

```
<?php

 namespace App;

 use Illuminate\Http\Request;
 use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
 use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;
 use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Input;

class Inquiryplan extends Model
{
protected $table = 'inquiry_plan';

protected $fillable = [
    'inquiry_id',
    'title_vacation',
    'email',
    'phone_no',
    'start_date',
    'end_date'
];

public $timestamps = false;

public static function SaveOrUpdate(Request $request) {
    try {
        $id = $request->get('id', false);
        $plandetails = false;
        DB::transaction(function () use ($request, &$plandetails, $id) {
            $plandetails = $id ? Inquiryplan::findOrFail($id) : new Inquiryplan();
            $plandetails->fill($request->all());
            try {
                $plandetails->save();
            } catch (\Exception $ex) {
                throw $ex;
            }
        });
        return $plandetails;
    } catch (\Exception $ex) {
        throw $ex;
    }
}}
```

Before saving a data on `inquiry_plan` table, one entry should go to the `inquiry_master` table.How can i do this ?

Answer (score 1):

A couple things.  First, Laravel already has exception handlers built into most if not all of it's functionality so providing you own exception is redundant.  A good rule of thumb for this is - if you are expecting an error, this is not the case to use an exemption.  So you can refactor this code significantly.  As for the additional database entry, simply insert it before your inquiry_plan table logic:

```
public static function SaveOrUpdate(Request $request) {

    $id = $request->get('id', false);
    $plandetails = false;

    DB::transaction(function () use ($request, &$plandetails, $id) {

        $planDetails = $id ? Inquiryplan::findOrFail($id) : new Inquiryplan();

        //plan_master
        $inquiryMaster = ...

        //plan_details
        $planDetails->fill($request->all());
        $planDetails->save();

    });
    return $planDetails;
}}
```

Hopefully this helps!

As an aside, I would recommend splitting the create and update tasks into different controller methods...makes the code cleaner and helps for maintainability down the road.